# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'

Tags: gdal

When trying `from osgeo import gdal` I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'`. I installed gdal 3.5.1 from binary.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gdalinfo --version` if you have an error like this : `gdalinfo: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.31: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
do this:

1. Find the location of libgdal.so.31 with the command `find / -name libgdal.so*`. for me the result was : `/usr/local/lib64/libgdal.so.31`
2. The folder where is located `libgdal.so.31` should be part of $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
   If it is not: add it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path_to_your_library` for my case it is `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
3. Try again `gdalinfo --version`, if it works try again to import gdal : `from osgeo import gdal` => Celebrate. If `gdalinfo --version` still work, repeat the process for error message specified libraries => celebrate